# how to handle back button function in AppStack version 4.0 ( headerLeft )?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-hooks

- in page ***app js***
- react :hook
  navigation : **version 4**
- **backLef**t error
  **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigation**
- I want to go back to the previous screen but the back () function doesn't work.
- the navigation & goback function not recognized.

```
import Info from "./Screens/Info";
import Note from "./Screens/Note";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark" />
      <AppContainer />
      <View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Start: {
      screen: Start,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: '',
      },
      params: { user: 'me' },
    },

    Info: {
      screen: Info,
      navigationOptions: { title: 'الصفحة الرئيسية' },
    },
    Guide: {
      screen: Guide,
      navigationOptions: { title: 'دليل الصيانة' },
    },
    Note: {
      screen: Note,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'المذكرة',
// **the error is here ⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇❌❌❌❌❌❌**
        headerLeft: () => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { goBack() }} ><Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>back</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      },
    },

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Start",
  
  
   
    },

  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppStack);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Note: {
  screen: Note,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'المذكرة',
    headerLeft: () => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }} ><Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>back</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  }),
},
```

You can access `navigation` object in `navigationOptions` as above and then it will be used to navigate route.

Comment: // go back and rerender with replace 
 navigation.replace('Info')